# Cannot implicitly convert type string to int asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

So i am trying to have a ternary operator inside the viewmodel. NOTE: RegionId is int. This is the code

```
 var model = (from p in _context.ProductGun
              where p.ProductId == productId
              select new GunViewModel)
              {
                  RegionId = p.RegionId == 1 ? "DEV" : "TEST"; //error
              }
```

I've tried:
        `RegionId = p.RegionId.ToString() == "1" ....;` 
        `RegionId = p.RegionId == Convert.ToInt32(1);` 
And vice versa solutions. But nothing is correct. Sorry for the typo. I type this using mobile

Comment: You cannot convert "DEV" to `int`...

Comment: If `RegionId` is an int, why do you think its ok to assign it "DEV"?  "DEV" is a string, _not_ an `int`

Comment: should it be from p in _context.ProductGun
              where p.ProductId == productId
              select new GunViewModel
              {
                  RegionId = p.RegionId == 1 ? "DEV" : "TEST"; //error
              } the ) is in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

I changed the datatype of RegionId in Viewmodel to String. Since it is int to int, It cannot implicitly convert type.

`RegionId = p.RegionId == 1 ? "DEV" : "TEST";
Where:
RegionId = string
p.RegionId = int`

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that RegionId is an Int and your trying to assign "DEV" to it anytime the region id is a 1.  thats not going to work.  try putting a zero  in it and checking for that anywhere you are looking for "DEV"

```
RegionId = p.RegionId == 1 ? 0 : p.RegionId;
```